# Polymer - Accessing DOM input element inside a custom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

**I just started working SNAP with polymer & everything seems to work fine for me,except that i am not able to access or set the value to the input field that is under a custom element. Please guide me through as to how to access/set the value to it. The code is as follows..**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <script src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <polymer-element name="proto-element">
      <template>
        <div class="div2">
       Source:<input type="text" id="textsrc" value="SOURCE"><br>
        Destination: <input type="text" id="textdest"><br>
        Flight:<input type="text" id="textplane"><br>
       </div>
      </template>
      <script>
        Polymer('proto-element',{ 
          ready: function() {
                var s = Snap(900,700);
                var rec1 = s.rect(50,200,150,80);
                var rec2 = s.rect(350,200,150,80);
                    rec1.attr({
                      fill: 'lightblue',
                      stroke: 'lightblue',
                      strokeOpacity: .3,
                      strokeWidth: 10,
                      id : 'id111' 
                    });


                    rec2.attr({
                      fill: 'lightblue',
                      stroke: 'lightblue',
                      strokeOpacity: .3,
                      strokeWidth: 10,
                      id : 'id112' 
                    });

    document.querySelector('#id111').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var txtboxval = document.querySelector("proto-element > #textsrc");
    alert(txtboxval.value);

      })
    });
     </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer has a nice feature called automatic node finding, since the `id` of any element only makes sense under the shadow subtree Polymer saves it under `instance.$` where instance is any instance of the `proto-element` you create.

In any method like `ready` you can access any element that has an id using `instance.$`, therefore instead of:

```
document.querySelector('#id111').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var txtboxval = document.querySelector("proto-element > #textsrc");
   alert(txtboxval.value);
})
```

You can use:

```
var me = this;
document.querySelector('#id111').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   var source = me.$.textsrc;
   alert(source.value)
}
```

More info about this feature [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding)

**Bonus:** the `textsrc` input can also be accessed with a querySelector using the following query:

```
var textSrcEl = document.querySelector('html /deep/ #textSrc');
```

It'd be a bad idea though, if you had multiple instances of `proto-element` then `querySelector` would just get the first one, you more info about selectors in shadow dom [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)

Answer (score 0):

I show you a rapid solution but i think is not the right way: you should use databinding[1] to do this type of interaction.

https://gist.github.com/alessandro-aglietti/116395f873402488217b

[1] https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html